# composer install fails on heroku after upgrading to symfony3

Tags: symfony, heroku, composer-php

I've just updated my app to Symfony3 (including directory structure).

On my dev environment everything works perfect but after deploying to heroku I get error:

```
[RuntimeException]                                                         
An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command:  
Could not open input file: app/console
```

Strange thing is that, when I run same command through heroku bash:

```
$ heroku run bash
$ composer install --no-dev
```

everything works fine...

I have a required `extra` filled in in `composer.json`:

```
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "symfony-var-dir": "var",
    "symfony-bin-dir": "bin",
    "symfony-tests-dir": "tests",
    "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml",
        "env-map": {
            "database_host": "MYSQL_HOST",
            "database_name": "MYSQL_DB",
            "database_user": "MYSQL_USER",
            "database_password": "MYSQL_PASSWORD"
        }
    }
}
```

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include the `var` directory (but not all of its content) in your git repository (you can shamelessly copy the configuration from the standard edition skeleton at https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard).

If you don't, the composer post-install scripts get confused as they determine your symfony version upon existence of the `var` directory at the application root and decide where the console script is.

Comment: I have `var` in my git repository. My `.gitignore` contains: `/var/`
`!var/cache/.gitkeep`
`!var/logs/.gitkeep`

Comment: You were right... `.gitkeep` in `var/cache` wasn't enough. I had to create anotherone in `var` and fore-add it to repository. Thanks a lot !